# To what story is Harlan Ellison referring?

Tags: story-identification, harlan-ellison

In ”Dreams with Sharp Teeth”, Harlan Ellison mentions a story whereby every thought is known to everyone, but a man still manages to get away with murder. Presumably, this is a story of his, or by someone he respects, as he refers to it as an example of a ”real” sci-fi story.

Anybody know which one he's talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for a story where the protagonist defends against mind reading by repeating a counting-out rhyme](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180855/looking-for-a-story-where-the-protagonist-defends-against-mind-reading-by-repeat)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost certainly *[The Demolished Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Demolished_Man)* by Alfred Bester, which is certainly a murder mystery set in a telepathic society (although telepaths are only a small minority).

Comment: An absolute classic, which every serious SF fan should read.  If Ellison was referring to this story, the description of "everything being known to everyone" was not correct.  There are other, spoilery reasons why the quote probably isn't referring to the this book.

Comment: It's certainly possible I misremembered the quote...it could have merely been "some" people to whom the thoughts would be known...

Comment: He is almost definitely referring to Bester - Ellison is a huge fan, and has written an introduction to Bester's *The Computer Connection*.