# Looking for a story where the protagonist defends against mind reading by repeating a counting-out rhyme

Tags: story-identification, telepathy

Don't know much for sure about this story. I've never read it; only heard a review at some point in mid-nineties on Polish TV. The author may very well be Polish, but there's a chance it was a translation (Yup, I'm also asking elsewhere in Polish).

The story is set in the world with telepaths and the protagonist has secret information (or maybe is a secret agent - not sure about this) and keeps repeating a rhyme in his (her?) head which blocks telepathic prodding of their mind. One thing I'm pretty sure I remember is the rhyme in Polish (It's actually been stuck in my head since the 90s) - and in Polish it indeed rhymes (AABB - end of lines) so most likely the translation was not literal. Re-translated back to English it would be something like:

> one - two - three and four
>   sultan liked bayaderes,
>   five - six - seven - eight
>   he liked to cock a snook at everyone.

and in Polish:

> raz - dwa - trzy i cztery
>   lubił sułtan bajadery,
>   pięć - sześć - siedem - osiem
>   lubił wszystkim grać na nosie

Comment: *The Demolished Man* was serialized in the [January](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v03n04_-_1952_01_-_Galaxy), [February](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v03n05_-_1952_02_-_Galaxy), and [March](https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v03n06_1952-03), 1952, issues of *Galaxy Science Fiction*; links to the Internet Archive.

Comment: Not what you're looking for, but this is a common trope. Non-psychic politicians are trained to do it in the [Saga of the Exiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saga_of_Pliocene_Exile) as a defence against casual psychic intrusion.

Comment: @Valorum How common was it in 1951? Was Bester's story the first instance of that "trope"?

Comment: @user14111 - Good question. Probably

Comment: Also in Midwich Cuckoos (aliens impregnate all the girls in a town, the kids grow up to be telepathic) by John Wyndham who wrote Day of the Triffids.  But he thinks of a brick wall.

Comment: I want to say that either Diadem or Artemis Fowl also had something like this, but I can't remember where.

Answer (score 45):

Other than the exact text of the rhyme, it sounds like a perfect match for Alfred Bester's *The Demolished Man*.  The main character wants to commit a crime in a world of telepaths and needs to keep it secret, so he fills his head with a catchy bit of verse -- a mindworm.

Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Demolished_Man

The mindworm is:

> Eight, sir; seven, sir;
>   Six, sir; five, sir;
>   Four, sir; three, sir;
>   Two, sir; one!
>
> Tenser, said the Tensor.
>   Tenser, said the Tensor.
>   Tension, apprehension,
>   And dissension have begun.

If this is indeed the right story, I'm guessing that the translators gave up on anything like a literal translation and tried to make something up in Polish which had the same effect.

Comment: Now that's a tongue-twister.

Comment: Nothing says "I am completely innocent with nothing to hide" than repeating a nursery rhyme over and over around telepaths

Comment: @simon_smiley In this story it was an advertising jingle*, deliberately chosen because it was the sort of thing that might get stuck in one's head.

(*well, more like the "thinking music" for a game show, but the reasons for that are wordy)

Comment: @Crashworks "Thinking Music" as in Jeopardy theme?

Comment: How odd. I'm convinced I've read a book or story containing this trope, but it certainly wasn't this one.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed, Alfred Bester's 'The Demolished Man' where the protagonist Ben Reich plans the murder of a business rival.  He uses a 'jingle' from an associate songwriter that acts as an earworm to block his murderous intentions from Espers.

[image: cover]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Demolished_Man):

> Reich contacts D'Courtney and proposes a merger of their concerns but Reich's damaged psychological state causes him to misread D'Courtney's positive response as a refusal. Frustrated and desperate, Reich determines to kill Craye D'Courtney. The presence of peepers has prevented the commission of murder for more than 70 years so Reich devises an elaborate plan to ensure his freedom. If caught Reich will certainly face "Demolition", a terrible punishment described only at the end of the story.
>   [...]
>   To further conceal his intentions from telepaths, Reich visits a songwriter, Duffy Wygand (spelled "Wyg&" in the text) who teaches him a deceptively simple jingle:
>   Eight, sir; seven, sir;
>   Six, sir; five, sir;
>   Four, sir; three, sir;
>   Two, sir; one!
>   [...]
>   This proves to be an earworm, so persistent and involving that it blocks most Espers from properly peeping into Reich's mind.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the existing answer.

Comment: the pretty picture though...